# xpath generate random number

Tags: xpath, random, xpath-1.0

Is there a way to generate a random number with xpath? My input is any well-formed xml, the output should be a random integer of a given length.
I usually achieve it with any coding or xslt but I'm struggling to find a working xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 3.1 has a function `fn:random-number-generator()`.

In earlier XPath versions you'll need to improvise.

When asking XPath questions please say which version you are using - the ancient XPath 1.0 is still in widespread use so it's impossible to make guesses.

Comment: Hi, I need to achieve it with xpath 1.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is the top google result, I'll say in XPath 3.1, Mr. Kay's answer can be achieved like this:

Say you want a random element. Count the elements:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="random-upper-limit" select="count(/myroot/mypath/myelement)"/>
```

Then get a random index number:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="my-random-number" select="random-number-generator()['next']?permute(1 to $random-upper-limit)[1]"/>
```